# "Next" button appearing when shouldn't

Tags: jquery, function, button, schema, slice

I'm have a function, below, that is comparing the text in two selectors. If the last occurrence of both of these selectors is the same, the "next" button will disappear. Currently, this is not working. I'm not sure why this is happening. Just fyi, what I'm trying to select is a schema 'itemprop' and is somewhat atypical.

Here is the fiddle - 
https://jsfiddle.net/carbot3000/8qjdxsz7/3/

```
function showHide(){
  if ( $('#areall span[itemprop="reviewBody"]').last().text().trim() == $('.review span[itemprop="reviewBody"]:visible').last().text().trim())
   {
     $('.next').hide();
  }
  else if ($('#areaall span[itemprop="reviewBody"]').first().text().trim() == $('.review:visible span[itemprop="reviewBody"]').first().text().trim())
   {
     $('.prev').hide();
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your `showHide` function like this.

```
function showHide(){
if ( $("#areaall").children().last().index() == $("#areaall .review:visible").last().index())
  {
    $('.next').hide();
  }
  else if ($("#areaall").children().first().index() == $("#areaall .review:visible").first().index()) {
    $('.prev').hide();
  }
}
```

Refer this [`Updated Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/8qjdxsz7/4/)

Comment: I have created another question (and fiddle) that is related to my original question; however, the issue is different. 

If you can, I would appreciate additional help - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39480825/jquery-href-attribute-not-getting-disabled